# how to change value of html element by classname using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, anchor, innerhtml

Here is the code i am using to change value of html element ***

```
<a class="classname" href="Vtech.com"> This text to be chnage</a>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].innerHTML = "aaaaaaqwerty";
</script>
```

how can I change this text on page load instans

Comment: [its working see here](http://jsfiddle.net/6bs80t79/)

Answer (score 11):

Seems you need to add `DOMContentLoaded` or put your script before `</body>`

Native JavaScript solution

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].innerHTML = "qwerty";
});
```

---

Add your script before `</body>`

---

Version with jQuery

```
$(funtion(){
   $(".classname:first").text("qwerty");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selector, but it can be not safe, because this method return first occurance:

```
document.querySelector(".classname");
```

By the way, almost all developers use some js framework: jQuery, prototype, extJs, etc

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery (I refered to jquery, since you have tagged it in your question), you could achieve this like below:

```
$(funtion(){
    $("a .classname")[0].text("aaaaaaqwerty");
});
```

Comment: No, `$(".classname")[0]` will retrieve the DOM node from the jQuery collection, which has no `text()` method. You could use `$(".classname").eq(0).text('...')` though.

Comment: @DavidThomas you are correct ! Thank you very much. I think that my edit also do the same thing that you referred to. Correct? I mean the selector is correct now. Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(funtion(){
    $(".classname").text("aaaaaaqwerty");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### You could use this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].innerHTML = "some texts";
});
```

### Using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".classname").eq(0).val("aaaaaaqwerty");
});
```

Comment: No, `$(".classname")[0]` will retrieve the DOM node from the jQuery collection, which has no `val()` method. You could use `$(".classname").eq(0).val('...')` though. Or you could, if the `<a>` element had a `val()` method.

Comment: @DavidThomas. Thankx for your valuable comment. I've edited my answer