# Change value of html element by classname using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li class="list-promotions">
   <ul class="list-promotions-item">
      <li>
          <a href="http://example.com/link">offers</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

I try to use this javascript code: ([This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918478))

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].innerHTML = "qwerty";
});
```

It works, but it changes my HTML to:

```
<li class="list-promotions">
<ul class="list-promotions-item">qwerty</ul>
</li>
```

So I lost `<a>` tag and the `href` .

How I can solve this issue? I just want to change the `offers` to another text and keep the `<a>` tag

Note: I do not have access to the HTML code to set a class name for `<a>` tag and use the above javascript code.

Comment: Change the innerHTML of the `<a>` instead of whatever `classname` is (since there is no such element in your HTML)

Comment: plz be more specific about what you are asking and would be good if you provide us a working demo

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector(".list-promotions-item > li > a").textContent = "qwerty";
```

Comment: Thanks. this works, but it also remove the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML)
>   of an element.

You had not added the classname class in HTML to anchor tag.

```
<li class="list-promotions">
       <ul class="list-promotions-item">
          <li>
              <a href="http://example.com/link" class="classname">offers</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].innerHTML = "qwerty";
    });
```

You can learn more at: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

---

> Using Jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.list-promotions-item li a').html('qwerty');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<li class="list-promotions">
   <ul class="list-promotions-item">
      <li>
          <a href="http://example.com/link">offers</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. Actually I don't have access to the HTML code to set the class name for the `<a>` tag. the HTML code is inside of a CMS.

Comment: @User check my updated answer using jquery where you don't need to provide class to anchor tag

Comment: Thank you, your code does not work for me. seems like I cant use jQuery code to customization this CMS. all I have found was change header.php file and use my own code to do what I want.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur jQuery is useless for cases like this. Furthermore, the OP is not using jquery or has named it.